# How to get javascript to add a class to an LI tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the function, "check letter" to see if the button the user has clicked matches a letter in the phrase and if it does, add "show" as a class to its LI element.

// Linking DOM Elements, to variables in javascript

```
    const letters = document.getElementById('qwerty');
    const letter = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    const keyWords = document.querySelector('#phrase');
```

// Array of phrases user will have to guess

```
     var phrases = ['Apple and Orange', 'Texas California Florida', 'Hampton Suites'];
```

// Choosing a random Phrase.

```
    function getRandomPhrase(arr){
    var randomPhrase = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    return randomPhrase;
   }
     let winningWords = getRandomPhrase(phrases);

      addPhraseToDisplay(winningWords);
```

// check if a letter is in a phrase

```
    function checkLetter(button){
    let letter = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
     let match = ' ';
     for (let i = 0; i< letter.length; i++){
    const li = letter[i];
    if(button.textContent === li.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase() ){
        match = li.classList.add('show');
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}
return match;
 }
```

// Adding Event Listener to buttons

```
   letters.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const button = e.target;

   if (button.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
    button.classList.add('chosen');
   }

  checkLetter(button);


  });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] if there is an issue. Otherwise, what is the question?